# How to get an object from one key,value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have the following code which returns whether the key and value are found in an array object.

```
function iterate(array, prop, val) {
    Object.keys(array).forEach((key) => {
        if (key === prop && val === array[key]) {
            console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${array[key]}`);
        }

        if (typeof array[key] === 'object') {
            iterate(array[key], prop, val);
        }
    });
}
```

That's ok but now I would like to access the full content of that specific object where those properties and values were found. This is my JSON:

```
[
   {
      "page":"main",
      "content":[
         {
            "type":"item",
            "item":[
               {
                  "name":"HAMMER",
                  "price":"1000"
               },
               {
                  "name":"SWORD",
                  "price":"2000"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

This is what I look for/get with my function:

```
"name":"HAMMER"
```

And this is what I need:

```
{
   "name":"HAMMER",
   "price":"1000"
},
```

Is there any way to achieve that or am I addressing this problem from the wrong perspective?

Comment: Instead of logging the found key/value, `return array;` (which isn't an array btw)

Comment: That's working and it is an object, right? Not an array. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisG that's not going to actually return anything from `iterate`

Comment: @VLAZ Right, I should look at the actual code maybe ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a basic loop, to find an item from deep nested object...

```js
let data = [{ "page": "main", "content": [{ "type": "item", "item": [{ "name": "HAMMER", "price": "1000" }, { "name": "SWORD", "price": "2000" }] }] }]
let [prop, value] = ["name", "HAMMER"]

loop: for (let page of data) {
    for (let type of page.content) {
        let found = type.item.find(v => v[prop] === value);
        if (found) {
            console.log(found)
            break loop;
        }
    }
}
```

would you like to lookup recursively? Then you can use a generator...

```js
let data = [{ "page": "main", "content": [{ "type": "item", "item": [{ "name": "HAMMER", "price": "1000" }, { "name": "SWORD", "price": "2000" }] }] }]

function* iterate(arrayLike, prop, value) {
    for (let page of arrayLike) {
        if (page[prop] == value)
            yield page;

        for (let v of Object.values(page)) {
            if (Array.isArray(v))
                yield* iterate(v, prop, value)
        }
    }
}

for (let item of iterate(data, "name", "HAMMER")) {
    console.log(item)
}
```

Comment: This is not a bad approach either but what did the trick was just modifying the log to get the whole array and not the filtered array. Thank you!

Comment: this is not filtering , but find a specific item, so did you looking for recursive iteration?

Comment: If so , I will update my question

Comment: No, I mean my code that I filtered. Your's is working fine. And yes, I was looking for a recursive iteration.

Comment: It does. Thank you!